Kendo react grid sort direction always asc
Problem
I’m trying to implement custom sorting in a React Kendo Grid using the built-in onDataStateChange function. However, the sort direction is always stuck on 'asc' and does not switch to 'desc', no matter the interaction.
Here is the relevant code snippet for the Kendo Grid and the onDataStateChange handler:
<Grid
    data={dataState.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        [SELECTED_FIELD]: selectedState[idGetter(item)]
    }))}
    style={{ maxHeight: '60vh' }}
    className={country?.Code === 'ca' ? 
    'documents-table entry-documents-table flex-fill' : ''}
    total={dataState ? dataState.length : 0}
    dataItemKey={DATA_ITEM_KEY}
    selectedField={SELECTED_FIELD}
    sortable={true}
    onDataStateChange={onDataStateChange}
>
    <Column field={SELECTED_FIELD} cell={GridCell} headerCell={HeaderCell} />
    <Column
        field='documentType'
        title={translate('DocumentType_Label')}
        cell={GridCell}
        width={country?.Code === 'ca' ? 240 : 330}
        sortable={true}
        columnMenu={ColumnMenuSearchText}
    />
    {country?.Code === 'ca' && <Column field='Version' title={translate('Version_Label')} cell={GridCell} />}
    <Column
        field='Date'
        title={translate('ImageDate_Label')}
        cell={GridCell}
        width={country?.Code !== 'ca' ? '100' : ''}
        sortable={true}
        columnMenu={ColumnMenuSearchText}
    />
    <Column field='Download' title=' ' sortable={false} cell={GridCell} locked {...(isMobile && { width: '20' })} />
</Grid>
const onDataStateChange = (e: GridDataStateChangeEvent) => {
    if (e?.dataState?.sort && Array.isArray(e.dataState.sort) && e.dataState.sort.length > 0) {
        const sortInfo = e.dataState.sort[0];
        const sortField = sortInfo.field;
        const sortDirection = sortInfo.dir;

        console.log('Sort Direction:', sortDirection);
        console.log('Sort Field:', sortField);

        if (sortedColumn === sortField) {
            setSortDirection((prevDirection) => (prevDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'));
        } else {
            setSortedColumn(sortField);
            setSortDirection('asc');
        }
    }
};

Issue
The sort direction (sortDirection) remains always 'asc' and does not switch to 'desc'. Despite interacting with the grid's sort functionality, the direction is stuck.
Expected Behavior
I expect the sortDirection to toggle between 'asc' and 'desc' based on user interactions with the grid's sort headers. If the user clicks on a column header that is already sorted, the direction should toggle.
Additional Information
I am using sortable={true} on the Column components.
I need to use the columnMenu property for filtering, so I am unable to implement custom sorting via header cells directly.

The issue was resolved after I removed custom cell from the column which I wanted to sort.
